# Get logged in user info - call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, runtime-error

I have a wordpress site and I want to display the info of the logged in user (eg. his username) in a php page.I've seen related posts to this and I tried this:

```
    <?php 
     global $current_user;
     get_currentuserinfo();
     echo $current_user->user_login;
    ?>
```

However, I'm getting an error "Call to undefined function"...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are calling a function that is undefined. You need to include some wordpress files first.

Comment: What does `get_currentuserinfo()` returns ? If object is to be returned then you'd have to use `$current_user = get_currentuserinfo()` .

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, when I include the file, other undefined functions appear...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably insert pluggable.php before calling get_currentuserinfo() function.
More info [here](http://www.saphod.net/2009/01/28/call-to-undefined-function-get_currentuserinfo/).

Comment: I did, but then errors of other undefined functions appear in the pluggable.php file and it's very strange, because the file is like that by default... :/